# PowerShell Get-SPSite https://

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, https

Greetings,

I'm trying to use the below to get a SharePoint site but it doesn't like the https.

$site = Get-SPSite https://some.url.com

Anybody know how to get an SSL enabled SPSite using Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: In what sense "doesn't like"? Can you provide more details - e.g., what messages it spits out (if any)?

Comment: What error do you see? Can you post the completely output of this cmdlet?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same command with HTTPs based SharePoint sites. Might be worthwhile checking to see if there is a alternate access mapping setup for HTTPS